# How to generate a list based on formula results

Tags: excel, list, concatenation

I need to generate a list of values found in `Column B`, but I only want to include rows where the formula in `Column F` tests **TRUE**.  This would ideally be a list contained within one cell where all the values from `Column B` are listed, separated by commas.

As an example:

```
  |    B    |    ...    |    F
----------------------------------
1 |    15   |           |  TRUE
2 |    10   |           |  TRUE
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:** *"15,10"*

I've tried `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX`/`MATCH`, but have thus far gotten nowhere.

Comment: are F1 and F2 actual boolean values `TRUE` or `FALSE` or are the text strings?

Comment: You will probably need to write a VBA macro to do this. I don't think it can be done with a formula. You *could* do this: `=CONCATONATE(IF(F1,B1 & ",",""),IF(F2,B2 & ",",""),IF(F3,B3 & ",",""), etc...)` but that would get tedious fast. It would also leave you with a trailing comma.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the attempts you made using `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX`/`MATCH`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `TEXTJOIN` function (Office 365, Excel 2016+), you can do it with a single formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(F:F=TRUE,B:B,""))
```

This is an array formula, and you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]

If your Excel does not have `TEXTJOIN` you will likely need VBA.

And you should shorten the whole column ranges that I used.  Smaller ranges will improve computation speed.  You could use either a dynamic range reference, or some size that is sure to encompass the entire data set.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Excel 2013, and don't have the TEXTJOIN Function available.  I've dabbled in VBA, but am not comfortable writing my own code from scratch.  Can you give me a basic example as to how I would achieve the required function using VBA?  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielKantor There are numerous articles on `SO`.  Just search SO for something like `TextJoin VBA`